# Camera on Android Emulator 4 to be HIGH DEF

Tags: android, camera, emulation

I`m new in Android development. I work with Android version 4.x, and it has emulated web cam with very low resolution, like 640x480.

I need to make an emulated webcam so it will work in high-def modes, like (4320x2880). In android 2.x I used variables hw.camera.maxHorizontalPixels and hw.camera.maxVerticalPixels, but it looks like they don't work any more in Android 4.x emulator of webcam.
Please assist, how to set high-def camera resolution in new emulator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short form: there does not appear to be an option for this today.

Long form: `devices.xml`, in your Android directory (e.g., `~/.android/`), uses <strike>[this XML schema](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/sdk/+/master/device_validator/dvlib/src/main/resources/com/android/dvlib/devices.xsd)</strike> an XML schema that I cannot find anymore. The only configurable options for the camera appear to be location (front/back), flash, and autofocus. Since `devices.xml` is what now controls what your emulator behaves like, it would appear that there is no equivalent to the old resolution options.

Comment: Link in your answer is no longer active. Please, update it

Comment: @Sergey: Sorry, I have no idea where they moved that to, or if it even exists anymore.